# JS special character not being displayed

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm updating the page title after some content is refreshed using AJAX, but the double arrow character is not displaying. Is there away to make this work?

```
document.title = title+' « Dyne Drewett';
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
document.title = title + ' \u00AB Dyne Drewett';
```

It might also be possible to get things to just work if all your encoding settings are correct.  The above will definitely work, I think.

List of all codes for reference: http://www.digitalmediaminute.com/reference/entity/

Comment: Shouldn't it be AE (ASCII 174)?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the HTML entities wherever possible. That is a left angle quote.

```
&laquo; // left angle quote
&raquo; // right angle quote
```

Comment: In this case that won't work. He's not injecting new HTML, he's setting the title in JavaScript. It's necessary therefore to use JavaScript syntax to create those characters.

Comment: @Pointy is correct, I had tried that - sorry, I should have mentioned in my origianal post.